# How to change origin of multiple git repos?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I want to create multiple repositories inside one repository. These will be recursive. I already have a code of having 80-90 repositories. But i need to change the "origin" of each repository. 
So, i have two questions-

1. How can i create git repositories recursively?
2. (If .git is already present How can i change the "origin" of each repository?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why oh why would you ant to do this? *Eighty* repositories deep?

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can't setup git repository inside another git repository. Closest substitute would be [git submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).

Comment: It may not be 80 repos deep. But may br the one repo can have 10-20 .git repo projects. It is required as per project demand, to build along with submodules.

Comment: @keltar Could you please give more light on git submodules? How it can help me in fulfilling my intent.

Comment: @love depending on how you repositories organised on remote. Something like `git submodule foreach 'git remote set-url origin newremote.com:/path/to/git/dir/$path'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: [using submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) would mean:

- you can create your 80 repos independently of the main repo which will contain them: they can be hosted on (your disk/GitHub/GitLab/...)
- you declare those repos as submodule, which means you are using the appropriate origin url when typing [`git submodule add`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule):

  ```
  cd /path/to/main/repo
  git submodule add /url/to/submodule/repo
  ```

Then:

```
git submodule update --recursive --init
```

No need to change their `origin` after that.

That being said, if you still had to change their url, then, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235259/how-to-change-origin-of-multiple-git-repos#comment39311742_25235259) by [keltar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/744720/keltar):

> `git submodule foreach 'git remote set-url origin newremote.com:/path/to/git/dir/$path'`

Comment: thanks for detailed explaination!! One more doubt, if i aready have some code with 80 repos, i need to change the origin of all the repos. Then what should my approach? Or will the same approach will help me? Please suggest.

Comment: @love that wouldn't be the same approach as those 80 repos wouldn't be submodules. In that case, you would have to search (simple `find`) for all the  `.git/` folder, and execute in the parent folder of those `.git/` directories the `git remote set-url origin new-url`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage a bunch of repositories from a single repo, I suggest perhaps looking at the `repo` tool. Android uses this to manage the 100+ repositories that make up the Android Open Source Platform.

Comment: Thanks!! I will try it, and check the feasibility for my project.